# Long to wide format in R based based on one column

Tags: r

I am struggling with probably quite a simple exercise, I have a dataframe consisting of two columns. One is a unique identifier and one is an image scan number. One unique identifier can have multiple image scan numbers and I am looking to reshape the data so all the scan numbers that relate to an individual ID are in one columns.

So going from:

- ID       Scan Number
- 1         E43
- 1         E56
- 2         E65
- 2         E98

to

- ID   Scan Number1    Scan number2
- 1     E43             E56
- 2     E65             E98

For example
[Long Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dGVv.png)
I would like to reshape this to a wide format based upon the ID,

to: [Wide Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPSmP.png)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `tidyverse` approach. You data is in long format, so you have to reshape to wide. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(Var=paste0('Scan_Number_',1:n())) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Var,values_from=Scan_Number)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID Scan_Number_1 Scan_Number_2
  <int> <chr>         <chr>        
1     1 E43           E56          
2     2 E65           E98
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Scan_Number = c("E43", 
"E56", "E65", "E98")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), ID ~ paste0("Scan_Number", rowid(ID)), value.var = 'Scan_Number')
#   ID Scan_Number1 Scan_Number2
#1:  1          E43          E56
#2:  2          E65          E98
```

#### data

```
df <-  structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Scan_Number = c("E43", 
"E56", "E65", "E98")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```